# Uploading image to firebase storage and getting URL from storage to user database. But photoURL overwritten everything in user database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I tried to upload image to profile page. I successfully uploaded image to storage and got photoURL and updated user database. But after I submit there is only photoURL and other user data like userInfo, name, age are gone. Deleted.

I think I'm not getting something right here:

```
    async function uploadFile() {
      if (file) {
        const uniqueName = new Date().getTime() + file.name;
        const storageRef = ref(storage, uniqueName);

        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

        uploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          (snapshot) => {
            const progress =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log(`Upload is ${progress}% done`);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("Error uploading file: ", error);
          },
          async () => {
            try {
              const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
              console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
              setPhotoURL(downloadURL);

              const userDocRef = doc(db, "profile", userInfo.userID);
              await setDoc(userDocRef, { photoURL: downloadURL });
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error getting download URL: ", error);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
    uploadFile();
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `setDoc()` method (`await setDoc(userDocRef, { photoURL: downloadURL });`), you should use the `updateDoc()` one, which "updates some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document". More details in the Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).